RDWeb HTML5 client on On-Prem Deployment: Change internal resource URLs to public ones
On a client's RDWeb HTML5 deployment per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-deskt... we have set up the client.
However, while our RDGateway and other components are all set to 'connect.example.com' for the URL and server name to use, the RDWeb client is defaulting to rdgateway01.internalonly.example.com which isn't usable from the outside.  As such, connections that aren't on our internal VPN or internal network are failing.
With the old (and I mean REALLY old) preview versions, this URL the system is using for the logon page, etc. was the correct 'connect.example.com' settings.  Since the new version, however, it looks like there's no way to configure this.
Is there any way to tell RDWeb to use the proper URL publicly rather than use the internal FQDN that is NOT set in the RD Gateway and RD Broker systems?

Note that for now we just reverted the entire infrastructure to pre-changes backups and it's working again, but that cert won't live more than 6 days.

yes, there is. download Set-RDPublishedName.ps1 script and run it on the server side. it will ask u for desired FQDN to use for RDWEB.
https://github.com/dwj7738/My-Powershell-Repository/blob/master/Scripts/Set-RDPublishedName.ps1
